# Sending data using Avro objects, is there an advantage to using schema registry?

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I have an application where I generate avro objects using an AVSC file and then produce using them objects. I can consumer then with the same schema in another application if I wish by generating the pojos there. This is done with an Avro plugin. The thing I noticed is that the schema doesn't exist in the schema registry.

I think if I change my producer type/settings it might create it there (I am using kafka spring). Is there any advantage to having it there, is what I am doing at the minute just serialization of data, is it the same as say just creating GSON objects from data and producing them?

Is it bad practice not having the schema in the registry?

Comment: is there any chance of this schema changing in the future? if so, will you wipe all the data or will you want to still be able to read older data?

Comment: There may be a chance of the schema changing in the future, that is a good point so if we change the schema in the future we will get errors when trying to read the older data but if we create in the schema registry the schema will evolve.

Comment: What serializer are you using if not the Confluent ones, which do put the schemas in the Registry?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am using the confluent one to generate the objects but I can produce them objects without putting the schema into the registry.

Comment: The producer puts schemas in the registry on its own, then. You don't need to do it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question, "is there an advantage" - yes. At the least, it allows for other applications to discover what is contained in the topic, whether that's another Java application using Spring, or not.

You don't require the schemas to be contained within the consumer codebase

And you say you're using the Confluent serializers, but there's no way to "skip" schema registration, so the schemas should be in the Registry by default under "your_topic-value"

Comment: Wasn't using the Avro serializer.